# MSVC fails on static_assert on struct member

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Here's my test case, simplified to a minimal test case:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
    int i;
    static_assert(sizeof(i) > 1, "Wrong size");
};
static_assert(sizeof(Foo::i) > 1, "Wrong size");
int main () {
    Foo f{42};
    static_assert(sizeof(f.i) > 1, "Wrong size");
    std::cout << f.i << "\n";
}
```

This works fine on any version of GCC or Clang recent enough to support `static_assert`. But on MSVC 2015, the first `static_assert` gives me a compile error:

```
static-assert.cpp(4): error C2327: 'Foo::i': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
static-assert.cpp(4): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier
static-assert.cpp(4): error C2338: Wrong size
```

The other two asserts work as expected, if I remove the first one. I also tried it on VS2013 with the same results. The [documentation for C2327](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac27ea0d.aspx) talks about nested class member access, which doesn't seem relevant in any way I can see. What's going on here? Which compiler is right?

(Edited to add a third assert to make the problem clearer.)

Further edit: It doesn't actually seem to have anything to do with `static_assert`, because this fails with the same error:

```
struct Foo {
    int i;
    char array[sizeof(i)];
};
```

Again, this works fine in other compilers.

Comment: The `sizeof(i)` is really `sizeof(this->i)`, but you are not inside a function, so there is no `this`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Is that part of the standard (I don't know)? OP mentions this works on GCC and CLang. If this is the case, are those then incorrectly not catching this?

Comment: "The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is not evaluated, or a parenthesized type-id." This is not a parenthesized type-id, so all that's left is an expression. But `i` is not a valid expression at that point because there is no object `i` in scope. The closest thing is `this->i` but there is no `this`. I suspect that GCC added support for this as a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular issue and the problem was that MSVC 2013 does not support constant expressions thus both

```
static_assert(sizeof(i) > 1, "Wrong size");
```

and

```
char array[sizeof(i)];
```

require constant expressions which is not supported by the compiler.

This is valid in gcc though

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, `sizeof (decltype(i))` works in VS2013.